GLMER when I have a categorical predictor with more than two levels?
If I have a dependent variable with two possible outputs (0/1), and categorical independent variables as predictors, along with the necessity of including random intercepts in my model, what should I do if one of my predictors has three different levels? I want to be able to detect differences between the three levels directly in the model (a<b<c), not only with post-hoc comparisons, so that a mixed effect logistic regression model would not be a good option. I want to show that when the variable X assumes the level c there are more outputs as 1 than when X assumes the level b and, in turn, when X assumes the level b there are more outputs as 1 then when it assumes the level a.
I do not want to use a Bayesan model.
Thanks

"I want to be able to detect differences between the three levels directly in the model (a<b<c), not only with post-hoc comparisons, so that a mixed effect logistic regression model would not be a good option"---Why wouldn't this be possible? One could easily get the estimated marginal means (EMMs) from a logistic GLMM and simply compare the EMMs across the three groups (and their CIs). I'm also not sure what Bayes has to do with anything. That is more about your philosophy about uncertainty than how it solves your issues here.

Also, what is wrong with doing post hoc tests?

@PeterFlom Basically nothing, but I wanted to know whether there are more appropriate models to solve my problem

@ShawnHemelstrand so what would you suggest? Is the best option that of running a glmer codifying each factor's level using orthogonal sum to zero contrasts and then adding among the predictors X (both a vs b and b vs c)? I wanter to know whether there exist other GLMMs where I can directly see whether X (a vs b vs c) is significant

Is this what you want? You cannot code a contrast for all possible pairwise comparisons but it doesn’t sound like that’s what you want anyway.
